# SQL query to display the length and first 3 characters of ename column in emp table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

just as the question can we do something to get the length and first 3 characters of the employee name of one column

Please do not mark as answered or duplicate
i have the test tomorrow Advance SQL so I am trying to solve some imp question..
Please answer the problem

thanks again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi Shanu,
 You can use **LEN()**  or **LENGTH()**(in case of oracle sql) function to get the length of a column.

`SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name;` 

And you can use **SUBSTRING** or **SUBSTR()** function go get first three characters of a column.

```
SUBSTRING( string, start_position, length );
SELECT SUBSTRING( column_name, 1, 3 ) FROM table_name;
```

> To get both together use concatenation operator,

```
 SELECT LEN(column_name)||SUBSTRING( column_name, 1, 3 ) FROM table_name;
```

Hope you got what you need. Any issues, feel free to ask

Comment: Which database you are using? Function changes corresponding to databases

Answer (score 6):

We can use `SUBSTRING` or `SUBSTR()` function, go get first three characters of a column.

And then try this particular query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ename,1,3) 
    FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT LEN(EMPLOYEE_NAME),LEFT(EMPLOYEE_NAME,3) FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select len(ename) as Column_Length, left(ename,3) first_three_char from employee; ---------need to code your query. Should not use test format, will be confusing
```

You can also use substring function instead of left. Query will look  like
 Select len(ename) as Column_Length,substring(ename,1,3) first_three_char from employee;